# Career info meant for "Apps & Software" will be added to "Open source"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I try to add experience to the Apps & Software section of my Careers 2.0 profile, it is not added there. Instead, it gets added to the Open source section. The project was closed-source.

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps you took?

Comment: Same problem! I am at 'My profile' > (scroll down to Apps & Software) > click 'add an application...' > opens link http://careers.stackoverflow.com/import/project/xxxxxx in top says 'Add Project' > add url > click get project > goes back with an open source project added instead of Apps & Software

Comment: I'm having this problem also. It ends up showing in the Open Source section with a "0" under the app title, and clicking the app title doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

This was indeed a problem. It’s resolved now, though the projects added over the last few days will have this problem.

I didn’t want to take the liberty of changing them, since (due to the bug) I can’t know whether open source was intended or not.

Deleting them and re-adding them will put them in the right place, but is tedious of course. You can email me personally (matt@stackoverflow.com) if you’d like to direct me to your projects and have me fix them.

Comment: It goes into the Apps & Software section now, but clicking the title still does nothing and it still shows "0" underneath the title. I tried doing a shift+reload to clear my browser cache before re-adding it, so I don't think it's a browser cache thing.

Comment: Confirmed, and apologies. One more time?

Comment: Perfect! Removing it and re-adding it fixed everything.